# How to make each element change color when clicked?

Tags: javascript, onclick, event-handling, dom-events, mouseevent

I have this code written to change each square to a larger size when I
scroll over. How can I make them change color instead of size when clicked, one red,
one blue, one green? I am to, Use a data attribute on the elements to
store the color to be changed to.

**This is my JS code.**

```
for(var i =0; i<3; i++) {
      //new div
      var newDiv = document.createElement("div");

      //add click listener
      newDiv.addEventListener('cick', clickResponse);

      //add the div to the root of the body
      document.body.appendChild(newDiv);
}

//event _handler_ 
function click (event) {
  event.target.style.width= "200px";
  event.target.style.height= "200px"; 
}
function mouseOut(event) {    
  event.target.style.width= "100px";
  event.target.style.height= "100px";
}
function onMouseClick(event) {
   event.target.remove();    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully this will help you.

Because each div needs to have a unique color, they've been created individually, outside of the loop. They then get added to an array, which is iterated through in order to add them to the DOM, attach event listeners, and apply various CSS styles. Inside the click handler, we grab the value of the div's "data-color" attribute and use it to update the div's background-color style.

```
<script>
  var div1 = document.createElement("div");
  div1.setAttribute("data-color", "red");

  var div2 = document.createElement("div");
  div2.setAttribute("data-color", "green");

  var div3 = document.createElement("div");
  div3.setAttribute("data-color", "blue");

  var divs = [div1, div2, div3];

  for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
    divs[i].style.width = "50px";
    divs[i].style.height = "50px";
    divs[i].style.margin = "5px";
    divs[i].style.backgroundColor = "#CCC";
    divs[i].addEventListener('click', clickResponse);
    document.body.appendChild(divs[i]);
  }

  function clickResponse(event) {
    var bgColor = event.target.getAttribute("data-color");
    event.target.style.backgroundColor = bgColor;
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#clickMe').click(function(){
  $('.defaultColor').css({background:"green"});
})
})
```

```css
.defaultColor{
width:100px;
height:100px;
background:yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="defaultColor">color Change</div>
<button id="clickMe">click me</button>
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!